# insert row if table is empty, else update row (mysql)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

i have 2 tables "table1" and "table2" both have TIMESTAMP cols for starttime and endtime. i want something like

```
if (table2 is empty)
insert into table2 (table2.starttime, table2.endtime) value (table1.starttime, table1.endtime (last row))
else if (TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,table2.endtime(last row),table1.starttime(lastrow))<10)
update table2.endtime (last row) value (table1.endtime)
else
insert into table2 (table2.starttime, table2.endtime) value (table1.starttime, table1.endtime (last row))
```

i have tried different aproches but i am unable to get it working specially IF-ELSE and IS NULL check.
i can get last row as `(SELECT endtime from table1 order by endtime DESC limit 1)`so kindly ignore that part.
MySql version: 5.5.38

Comment: "Unable to get it working" is a little vague.  Are you getting a syntax error?  A run time error?  Is it running, but always following the first branch of your logic, or always the second?  Offhand, I don't believe MySQL recognizes `table is empty`.

Comment: Similar, may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476851/why-doesnt-this-if-not-exists-statement-work

Comment: @JonofAllTrades i am sorry i forgot to mention this is pseudo code. i have tried the following `IS EMPTY` `IS NULL`... i am getting a syntax error on `IF THEN ELSE`

Answer (score 1):

got it working but there might be better ways

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simple6(IN name VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN

SET @sql_text = concat('SELECT endtime INTO @endtime1 FROM ',name,'big order by endtime DESC LIMIT 1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;

if @endtime1 IS NULL
then

SET @sql_text2=concat('INSERT INTO ',name,'big (starttime,endtime) SELECT starttime,endtime FROM ',name,' ORDER BY endtime DESC LIMIT 1');
PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql_text2;
EXECUTE stmt2;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;

else
SET @sql_text3= concat('set @cat:= (IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,(SELECT endtime from ',name,'big order by endtime DESC limit 1),(SELECT starttime from ',name,' order by starttime DESC limit 1)) < 5,1,0))');
PREPARE stmt3 FROM @sql_text3;
EXECUTE stmt3;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;

if @cat !=0
THEN
SET @sql_text4=concat('UPDATE ',name,'big SET endtime = (SELECT endtime FROM ',name,' ORDER BY endtime DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1');
PREPARE stmt4 FROM @sql_text4;
EXECUTE stmt4;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;

else
SET @sql_text5=concat('INSERT INTO ',name,'big (starttime,endtime) SELECT starttime,endtime FROM ',name,' ORDER BY endtime DESC LIMIT 1');
PREPARE stmt5 FROM @sql_text5;
EXECUTE stmt5;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt5;

end if;
end if;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END\\
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you're looking for, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html ?

With this you can update only if the key exists.